# list characteristics in correct manner

Tags: lists

What is the best method of listing specific characteristics when writing scientifically. My example:

> The study sites range in area from 1000 m² to 1200 m², cover depths of 0.08 to 5.7 m, range in altitude from 0 to 100 m, and span latitudes of between −40 to 50 °N.

Note that XX here is a variable name.

I am not convinced that I am writing this in the best possible way. For example, am I using *cover*, *range*, *span* in the correct way here? Is there a specific rule to follow in scientific writing?

Comment: I feel like a math student, trying to find XX :(

Comment: I really do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Note that XX where? It's not mentioned anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the sites which 'range' but their areas, depths, elevations, altitudes and latitudes.

And a site spanning 90 degrees of latitude would have to be quite narrow to cover only 1200 m<sup>2</sup>!

I would write:

> The study sites vary between 1000m<sup>2</sup> and 1200m<sup>2</sup> in area, between 0.08m and 5.7m in depth, and between 0m and 100m in elevation, and lie in latitudes between 40°S and 50°N.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the sites range in area from X to Y, range in size from A to B, range in depth from C to D, just write

> The study sites range in area from 1000 to 1200 m^2, in depth
>   from 0.08 to 5.7 m, in altitude from 0 to 100 m and ...

(well, you'll have to finish the sentence yourself, I'm not sure if some of the sites are at latitude -40 and some at + 50 or if one (or more) site covers that whole range of latitudes).

Using 'range', 'cover', and 'span' looks, to this reader, like unnecessary variation inspired by a reluctance to use 'range' repeatedly.  Fair enough, but you don't need to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to use bullet points, as follows:

> Characteristics of the sites:
>
> - Area: 1000-2000 m^2
> - Depth: 0.08-5.7 m
> - Altitude: 0-100 m

This makes it easy for your readers to assimilate the information at a glance, and also avoids distracting you with the effort to get creative with your verbs.